Tefillin with runny nose
Can one put on tefillin when he is mildly sick, and might need to cough or blow his nose while wearing them, assuming he is able to keep his mind focused otherwise?

Sure. There's no issue with coughing or blowing your nose while wearing Tefillin.

Thank you - does that mean the "bodily functions" prohibition is specifically around functions related to the "lower body parts"?

Whilst this answer is correct, as per the format of the site, without sources this is no different to a comment?

@Dov How can I quote a non-existent source?

@Mxyitz There are restrictions related to the lower organs but you'd have to be more specific. There's no blanket prohibition on "bodily functions."

@shmosel then don't bother to submit it as an answer just write it as a comment.

@Dov I don't see how one follows from the other. Assuming the question is a valid question, Yes and No are both valid answers. Whether and how it's sourced is a technicality.

@shmosel I'll leave the mods to pass judgement
